# Fill closed object with water - maintaining volume

Tags: mathematics

I'm showing the problem in 2D, but basically given a volume V (can be approximate), where should the center point of an upwards facing plane P be for any given rotation of the object? I'm not doing a strict fluid simulation, it doesn't need to pool in isolated areas or slop around, it's just (I think) a volume preservation exercise.

To reiterate, V is known, P is what i'm trying to solve.

Do I need to voxelize the object and essentially count boxes from the lowest bounds up?

[image]

Edit: Here's the code based on Bálint's response. Note that I haven't tested it yet (you'd call the top function and the second one is iterative).

https://pastebin.com/N4Mimnwg

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Every object is made of triangles. If it isn't, then it can be approximated. You basically need to do a binary search. Get the lowest and highest point in the object and set P halfway between these. Now extract every triangle and create tetrahedrons from current P and the triangles with a center point lower, than P. Calculate their total volume, if it's less, than the target volume, then move P upwards half as much as before (you move it by half of the height of the object first, then quarter, then eighth, etc.). If it's less, then move it downwards. After you reached the precision you want, stop. The last P point is your best estimate.